# Drush pm-download removing the destination folder

Tags: drush

I'm creating a system to easily create new Drupal sites, using drush.
When I'm creating a new site, I just point the path where drush should create it and run `drush pm-download drupal-7.12 --destination=/var/www --drupal-project-rename=test11` (example) on it.
I saw that drush deletes the folder and then creates it again. Most of the time I still need the files that are in the folder (e.g. 404.html, 403.html etc)

There's any way I could use pm-download without deleting the current files in the folder?

Thanks

-- Info:

Drush version: 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of request is best made in the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drush), since what you are requesting is a change in behavior in Drush.  The default behavior for pm-download is to always provide a clean unaltered copy of the module; I for one would be reluctant to alter this behavior, but I could potentially get behind a new option that introduced 'merge' behavior.

A better option, I think, would be for you to download Drupal to a temporary folder, and do the merge yourself in your script as a secondary step.

Comment: Yeah, I think my only option here is to download the files to another directory and then move it to the correct path.
Thanks for the answer.